# mySQL convert string date to quarter

Tags: mysql, date

I have several fields in a sql table, including name, type, and date. In date, it is stored as a string "2016-05-01" format. I would like to count the number of occurrences of name grouped by each quarter date.

By this, I mean that name can occur multiple times in a month. I would like to count the number of times the names occur in groups of 3 months (quarters) and print the name, count, and quarter in each row.

So if for example I had the columns name, type, and date and ran the query 
it could result in

```
Name  Quarter    Count
Ron |    1    |   62   |
Ron |    2    |   32   |
Ron |    3    |   45   |
Ron |    4    |   33   |
Tim |    1    |   62   |
Tim |    3    |   62   |
```

and so on. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that  my_date_column is a date 
You can use quarter()

```
select Name, QUARTER(my_date_column), count(*)
frpm my_table 
group by name, QUARTER(my_date_column)
;
```

otherwise you should convert the string in date

for convert a string you can use

```
str_to_date('2016-09-20', '%Y-%m-%d')


select Name, QUARTER(str_to_date(my_strdate_column, '%Y-%m-%d')), count(*)
frpm my_table 
group by name, QUARTER(str_to_date(my_strdate_column, '%Y-%m-%d'))
;
```

Comment: How could I convert a string like "2016-09-20" to date format? Like I have used something like MONTH() before, but which function would give me correct date format needed?